# Placing an object on top of other object showing background object color

Tags: inkscape

*I am placing an object and placing it on top of other object using **Align and Distribute** but the other object background color is appearing as a stroke.*

Image one is showing two objects.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Possibly Helpful: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/130427/weird-grey-line-border-in-white-space-in-adobe-illustrator/130432#130432

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inkscape objects have 1 pixel wide fuzzy edge when they are rendered for the screen. It's the anti-aliasing and that's your problem.

A little bigger top object fixes your case. Insert for example a narrow stroke after the object is exactly in its place.

ADD due a comment:

Clipping has the same weakness. See an example:

[image]

Grey and red rectangles are placed under the green circle to get duocolored circle by applying Object > Clip. Grey and red rectangles have generous overlap to avoid partially transparent seam which would appear if the rectangles were faced exactly with no overlap.

In the right is the result of the clipping. A slight red ghost can be seen around the grey part. To minimize the ghost the overlap should be only 2 pixels.

Not asked: Clipped objects are still independent. It's very easy to select one and move it to a wrong place when the whole thing was intended to be moved. Selections are more sure when one selects parts in the Objects panel.

Comment: In illustrator I would recommend using the shape as a clipping path (like I explain in [this answer](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/91578/84899)). Isn't that possible in Inkscape?

Comment: @Wolff I insert something about it to the answer.