# Problem with Line Segment Tool

Tags: adobe-illustrator, information-graphics

I am trying to create an arc in illustrator and its turning into a big blob when I color the stroke. How do I make it so that I can use the arc tool, or create any simple line with no color fill, but color the stroke without it turning into a big distorted shape?

Also, when I create a simple shape and color the fill and stroke with two different colors, I can see that the stroke of the shape is a little distorted and does not align properly with the shape itself. How can I fix that?

Comment: The Line Tool is never mean to draw "arcs". Have you tried merely using the Pen Tool? As for the stroke/fill thing, more detail may be needed, but [**THIS**](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/130427/weird-grey-line-border-in-white-space-in-adobe-illustrator/130432#130432) may be relevant.

Comment: Try turning gpu acceleration off